# Exibir tags HTML sem formatação do Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Pessoal tenho uma coluna no banco onde eu digito posts do site. La eu faço toda a formatação com bold, alinhamentos, fontes e tudo mais. Só que quando eu vou exibir no site muitas configurações das tags ficam conforme o Twitter Bootstrap configura assim sendo desaparece por exemplo os marcadores. Como eu faço para exibir este conteúdo no site sem ter as modificações feitas pelo Twitter Bootstrap? Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

O que você precisa fazer é um contexto, ou *wrapper* como é comumente utilizado em CSS.

O contexto ou *wrapper* é um elemento (pai) que vai envolver vários elementos com regras específicas ou não.

Exemplo:

```css
p {color:blue;}
.wrapper p {color:red;}
```

```html
<p>Estou fora do contexto....</p>
<div class="wrapper">
   <p>Eu estou no contexto...</p>
</div>
<p>Eu também estou fora do contexto....</p>
```

Sendo assim você precisa criar um CSS com um *wrapper* que sobrescreva as regras do Twitter Bootstrap.

Uma forma bem simples de restar o CSS de um *wrapper*:

```
.wrapper * {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  vertical-align:baseline;
  color:black;
}
```

Aqui [um CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) bastante utilizado, para envolve-lo no *wrapper* basta adicionar a classe antes de todos os seletores.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa **sobrescrever** as configurações que os elementos estão recebendo do `Bootstrap`!
**Como fazer isso?**

coloque `!important` nas configurações que você deseja que sejam as prioritárias. Exemplo:

```
p { color: red !important; }
```

[Fonte](http://zenorocha.com/css-important/)

**EDIT:** Outra forma é colocar o `style` diretamente no html. Exemplo:

```
<p style="color: red;"> Olá mundo! </p>
```

Comment: olha eu pensei nisto. Mas se eu fizer isto eu vou também alterar o layout do site. Imaginei que teria alguma outra forma de fazer isto.

Comment: veja outra forma que coloquei